# Cant remove item with session array in shopping cart

Tags: php, session

I have a session array for shopping cart, but the problem is when I try to remove the selected item with UNSET command it seems not working. Somebody please help me. I like to remove the item based on product ID and Size, because some other item in my shopping cart may have same product ID with the different size. Here's my code below :

My shopping cart session structure :

```
$_SESSION['cart_items'][$id.'-'.$size] = array('id'=> $id,'code' => $code, 'Quantity' => $quantity, 'Size' => $size);
```

coding for delete item :

```
    $size = $_GET['Product_Size'];
$id = $_GET['Product_ID'];

echo $id.$size;

if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_items'])){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Shopping list is empty!');
        window.history.back();</script>";   
}

if (isset($_SESSION['cart_items'])) {
    //print_r($_SESSION['cart_items']);
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart_items'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == $id.'-'.$size) {
        unset($_SESSION['cart_items'][$key]);
    //print_r($_SESSION['cart_items']);
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successful remove!');
        window.history.back();</script>";   
        break;  
                                                         }
    else
        {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Not found!');
        window.history.back();</script>";     
        }    
                                                        }

}
```

Comment: How is it not working? Can you point out what is the output and what did you actually expect to do?

Comment: the output said "successful remove" like the echo that I placed. but when back to the shopping cart page, the item that I deleted before still at there. I already doing COUNT  and PRINT_R for my shopping cart to check it. The quantity result still the same before I deleted the selected item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `foreach` loop syntax you've made a logical mistake, the contents of the `$_SESSION['cart_items']` is an array having some keys and values, the keys are in the `$id-$size` format, and the values are arrays containing more information. So the "keys" are what you should to check against, Change your code as follows:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart_items'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == $id.'-'.$size) {
        unset($_SESSION['cart_items'][$key]);
        // ... (the rest of the code)
```

Comment: not worked. :( I tried to PRINT_R and the result was :

[0] => Array ( [id] => 9 [code] => X001 [Quantity] => 1 [Size] => Free ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 12 [code] => X004 [Quantity] => 3 [Size] => Free ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 10 [code] => X002 [Quantity] => 1 [Size] => M ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 10 [code] => X002 [Quantity] => 1 [Size] => S )

Comment: @Joe What was the argument to `print_r()` which produced the above output?

Comment: sorry for my mistake. that happen because I add another code like : 

$_SESSION['cart_items']=array_values($_SESSION['cart_items']);

but I already remove it. and now the result is : Array ( [ 9-Free] => Array ( [id] => 9 [code] => X001 [Quantity] => 1 [Size] => Free ) ) but the item still in cart when I tried to removed it.

Comment: @Joe I've tested it locally, no problems :) Have you noticed the space before the `9-Free` key? Also, please provide the output of `var_dump($_SESSION);` before the removing procedure.

Comment: I already updated the code. please help me.. I have been stuck for 3 days :(

Comment: Woaa, Thank you for saving my day someOne. the space before key its the problem. Thank you so much. :)